# Theorem 12.2; Ross: Elementary Analysis 2nd Ed.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am having trouble understanding a particular part of this proof for this theorem:

**Theorem 12.2**
Third Inequality:

*Let $(s_n)$ be any sequence of nonzero reals. Then we have*
$$ \limsup|s_n|^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \limsup|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}| $$

Proof

Let $\alpha=\limsup|s_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}$ and $L=\limsup|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}|$. We will prove that $\alpha \leq L$, in fact, we will prove that 
$$\alpha \leq L_1$$ for any $L_1 >L$.

By definition of limit superior, it follows that there exists a positive integer $N$ such that

$$|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}| \leq L_1$$
for $n \geq N.$

Now for $n>N$ we can write

$$|s_n|= |\frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}}|\cdot|\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_{n-2}}|\cdots|\frac{s_{N+1}}{s_{N}}|\cdot |s_N|$$

*(This part makes total sense to me however, I cannot resolve how the next part is obtained:)*

Applying our previous inequality, we have

$$|s_n|<L_{1}^{n-N} s_N$$

for $n>N$.

*In particular:
I am not sure if we obtained this inequality because 1:
$$|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}| \leq |s_n| \Rightarrow |\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}| \leq |s_n| <L_{1}^{n-N} s_N$$
or because 2:
$$|\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}| \geq |s_n| \Rightarrow |s_n| \leq |\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}|  <L_{1}^{n-N} s_N$$

I mean, I thought our argument was based on the ratio of two sequences, so then how can we just focus a new argument on the denominator??*

Answer (score 0):

Each of $$\left|\frac{s_n}{s_{n-1}}\right|,\left|\frac{s_{n-1}}{s_{n-2}}\right|,\ldots,\left|\frac{s_{N+1}}{s_N}\right|$$
is $\le L_1$ (this is because each is a $|s_{m+1}/s_m|$ with $m\ge N$).
Therefore their product is $\le L_1^{n-N}$, that is $|s_n|\le L_1^{n-N}|s_N|$.

Comment: Could we then say that, 

$$|s_n| \leq |\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}|$$

for $n>N$?